# plotting two overlapping surface graphs in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, surface

I get the following graph when I run

```
x1=0:0.01:1;
y1=0:0.01:1;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,y1);
Z=0.8.*X+0.2.*Y;
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

[image]

And when I separately run this code

```
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(a,b);
Z1=0.8.*X1+0.2.*Y1;
surf(X1,Y1,Z1,'EdgeColor','none');
```

I get the following

[image]

Here a,b are subsets of x1 and y1.

But what I want is I want to draw the second graph on top of the first surface graph. I used **hold on**, and used the code,

```
x1=0:0.01:1;
y1=0:0.01:1;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,y1);
Z=0.8.*X+0.2.*Y;
surf(X,Y,Z);
hold on;


[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(a,b);
Z1=0.8.*X1+0.2.*Y1;
surf(X1,Y1,Z1,'EdgeColor','none');
```

this is what I get

[image]

Why can't I see the second graph on top of this?

Comment: You're plotting the exact same surface, at least `z(x,y)` is the same. What do you expect? If you want one of them on top (which is undefined *a priori*, since you have two infinitely flat surfaces at the exact same coordinates), change the corresponding `z` components a bit, to ensure that it's above the other.

Answer (score 1):

The colors of the surface generated by [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) with this syntax are driven by their `Z` values. If you want coplanar surfaces to be visually separated you will need to adjust the [`FaceColor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartsurface-properties.html#zmw57dd0e664067) of one of the plots.

For example:

```
x1=0:0.01:1;
y1=0:0.01:1;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,y1);
Z=0.8.*X+0.2.*Y;
s1 = surf(X,Y,Z);

a = x1(40:70);
b = y1(40:70);
hold on;
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(a,b);
Z1=0.8.*X1+0.2.*Y1;
s2 = surf(X1,Y1,Z1, 'FaceColor', 'r', 'EdgeColor','none');
```

Gives us the following:

[image: yay]

Comment: Thanks. This works. But when I go to x-y view why do I see discrete lines. There's no continuous surface. Why is that?

Comment: @clarkson pleaaase tell me: what do you exactly expect to get?:)

Comment: @clarkson You still have edges on the first surface because you haven't turned them off in the code. You're going to see edges around the second surface because there's a discrete boundary where the color changes, known as an edge.